# Does Internet Explorer remove the <object> element from DOM?

Tags: internet-explorer, dom, dhtml, object-tag

I have markup in my page that includes the  tag:

```
<body>
  <object codebase="blah" codetype="text/blah">
    <param name="name" value="value"/>
    <div>Some Markup</div>
  </object>
</body>
```

The idea is for browsers to display the content of the `<div>` by default, but if a special JS library is present, it will find all the  elements and transform the ones it cares about (based on `@codetype`).

This works in Firefox and WebKit, but fails in IE, because that browser seems to strip off the outer `<object>` element, and just leaves the inner `<div>`. That is, under Explorer, the DOM I get from the above markup looks like this:

```
<body>
  <div>Some Markup</div>
</body>
```

Is this a documented behavior? Is there any way to make IE preserve the `<object>` element in the DOM untouched? (I am currently testing this with IE7.)

**Note**: This isn't for embedding Flash, or similar multimedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm... According to a post on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304133(VS.85).aspx#Fallback), Internet Explorer before version 7 would remove from DOM any `<object>` whose content couldn't be rendered.

I guess this makes my problem a catch-22. I can add some data that would make IE render the `<object>` (such as make it show a 1 pixel image), which would enable the Element in the DOM, but this would hide the "fallback" markup.

Answer (score 0):

To embed objects, I'd recommend using a library like [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/), because yes, IE is definitively doing something funky with this tag.

Comment: what kind of object are you trying to embed then?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to create an object, and it cannot be instantiated, it wouldn't surprise me if the object tag didn't end up being part of the DOM.