# IE gives "no such interface supported" message when inserting and <object> for a plugin

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I'm trying to insert a video player plugin into the DOM using an object.  This works fine with Firefox and Chrome, however I get a "no such interface supported" message from IE 8 and IE 7.  The plugin works fine in all three if it's in the HTML file the server sends out.

Here is what I'm trying to create:

```
<object id="plugin" width="220" height="360" type="application/x-ourmediaplayer"  
  <param name='mode' value='LIVE' />  
  <param name="ip_address" value='10.220.196.150' />  
  <param name='port' value='80' />  
</object>
```

If I use the following code I get the error on IE:

```
var container = document.getElementById('pluginContainer');  
var plugin = document.createElement('object');  
plugin.id = 'plugin';  
plugin['width'] = '220';  
plugin['height'] = '360';  
plugin['type'] = 'application/x-ourmediaplayer'>

var param = document.createElement('param');  
param['name'] = 'mode'; param['value'] = 'LIVE'; plugin.appendChild(param);

param = document.createElement('param');  
param['name'] = 'ip_address'; param['value'] = '10.220.196.150';
plugin.appendChild(param);    `

param = document.createElement('param');  
param['name'] = 'port'; param['value'] = '80'; plugin.appendChild(param);

container.appendChild(plugin);
```

Does anyone have any ideas?  Can I do this with IE, or is there some other way of appending an object of this type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be too late, but I've seen this same error in a variety of cases. It is probably nothing wrong with your code. It is most likely a problem with the installation of IE, registration of some DLLs. In this [thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/links-in-ie8-not-working-no-such-interface/635d4363-ca25-451e-8211-0265a25f115b) somebody pointed to some scripts which fix IE, [here](http://iefaq.info/index.php?action=artikel&cat=42&id=133&artlang=en).

Another [site](http://www.dcs-media.com/Archive/javascript-error-no-such-interface-supported-solved-HH), specifies:

> Register two DLL's using RegSvr32: actxprxy.dll and shdocvw.dll. After
>   you register those two DLL's, reboot your computer and try it again.
>   The message should disappear.

I hope that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I'm guessing that it's a IE's [mishandling of the object tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981856/does-internet-explorer-remove-the-object-element-from-dom).  Consider looking at the source for SWFObject for some ideas on how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but I didn't see anything to help me in in the SWFObject source.  Thanks for responding though.